# Making XSLT language independent

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

In my web application, I display the search results using XSLT.
There are some hard coded text in XSLT file which I want to make language independent.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:if test="$IsEmpty">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width:100%;border-top-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-right-style:solid;border-top-color:gray;border-bottom-color:gray;border-left-color:gray;border-right-color:gray;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-left-width:1px;border-right-width:1px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                There are no blog posts to display.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:if>
```

Is it possible to pick the text `"There are no blog posts to display."` from a resource file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "resource file" you mean a regular resx that is compiled into the assembly. In which case, not *directly* from xslt; however, you could add an extension object and use a key-base approach, i.e.

```
<xsl:value-of select="resx:getString('noposts')"/>
```

The "resx" alias would be mapped (`xmlns`) to a uri that you use when creating your xslt wrapper in C#. For example, with the `xmlns` (in the xslt preamble):

```
xmlns:resx="myextnuri"
```

we can map that in C# via:

```
public class MyXsltExtension {
    public string getString(string key) {
        return "TODO: Read from resx: " + key;
    }
}
```

and attach this to the namespace:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("xslt.xslt");
XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
object obj = new MyXsltExtension();
args.AddExtensionObject("myextnuri", obj);
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("out.xml")) {
    xslt.Transform("xml.xml", args, writer);
}
```

We now have full control to inject managed code (as extensions) into our xslt.

Comment: `msxsl:script` is yet another option.

Comment: I can't see how `msxsl:script` would provide access to resx; I'd love to see an example...

Answer (score 2):

You can load resources from an external file using the `document()` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="document('resources.xml')/items/item[@id = 'no_posts']"/>
          </p>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

XML resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <item id="no_posts">There are no blog posts to display.</item>
</items>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```